# Report Server: login failed to master database

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, ssrs, sql-server

I noticed from the SQL Server log that every time server restarts (I'm using SQL Server 2008 developer edition) I get an error message into log:

```
Login failed for user 'machine\sqlaccount'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

I can see details from the profiler trace and it shows that the application causing is Report Server and the database is master. How should I modify these privileges to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReportServer requires some rights in master and msdb, based on the RSExecRole

At some point, these have been lost eg RS account change, server migration etc

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281308.aspx) article shows you how to recreate it